# Prophet cannot be imported on Mac Miniconda

Tags: python, prophet

Hellow, everyone.

I want to try prophet on Mac and Miniconda environment.

I trieted below, but did not work.

try1. conda install

```sh
$ conda install gcc pystan fbprophet
```

try2. pip install

```sh
$ pip install fbprophet
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled, but result is the same.

Miniconda cannot use prophet ?

Comment: Define "did not work".

Comment: Sorry, did not work is below


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-76b95a198b1e> in <module>
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 
----> 5 from fbprophet import Prophet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fbprophet'

Answer (score 0):

This error was solved.

Module name is changed to prophet from fbprophet in official.

My set up instruction is below.

1. $ pip install prophet
2. from prophet import Prophet

I wish this helps someone.

Thank you every one.